# Why do React hooks use a const in the React Docs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm a little confused; might be more of a JS question.

```js
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState();

// The docs say that the above is equivalent to:
var someStateVariable = useState();
var someState = someStateVariable[0];
var setSomeState = someStateVariable[1];

// Why does it come out as a var and not a const?
// I'd imagine it do something like:

const someState = useState()[0]
```

I was initially confused on how `someState` can be edited despite being a `const`.

Comment: I think reason for using const could be you can't modify directly the variable which is someState in your case where as you should be modifying it by using method setSomeState.

Comment: `const` only prevents reassignment. You can still modify any mutable objects (Functions, Arrays, Objects) though you shouldn't modify a React's state object directly and only use its setter to do so.

Comment: _"Why does it come out as a var"_ I think it's only a small misleading thing in the doc, as it could (should) be a `const` as well.

Comment: It's probably just showing the ES5 equivalent (ES5 has no `const`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do:

```
const [someState, setSomeState] = useState()
```

You are using deestructuring assignment to access two elements returned from `useState`, the actual state's property and a way to change it (`updater`) when you change a state's property using an `updater` you aren't mutating the state, `React` will actually 'know' what was the property's previous value and will generate another instance based on the previous one. So you should face this iteration proccess as a new `const` is created uppon each render call, and the new one have no relation with the previous whatsoever.

> We declare a state variable called count, and set it to 0. React will remember its current value between re-renders, and provide the most recent one to our function. If we want to update the current count, we can call setCount.

Here is a fragment from the [offical docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) to clarify

Comment: Whats the difference between `[ ]` and `{ }` when destructuring?

Comment: Will depend of  the implementation. In this case we use `[]` cause the value returned from `useState` is an array containing 2 elements

Comment: Ohh gotcha.  `[ ]` is specifically used to destructure an array;  Where as `{ }` is to destructure objects. Thanks!